# Using gsub in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I have an html string (temp) as follows

```
  "                                <span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$138,110</span></dd>"
```

I would like to use gsub to only return the $138,110, without quotes or blank spaces.

So far I have done

```
  gsub("<.*?>", "", z[temp[3]])
```

but this only returns

```
  "                                $138,110"
```

Comment: use `trimws()` to remove any white space at the beginning or end of a string `trimws(gsub("<.*?>", "", z[temp[3]]))`

Comment: You should give up on the request to deliver without quotes since there are no quote-characters in the result. Those quotes are onlu informational and can be avoided by using `cat` or print with `quotes=FALSE`.Look for `trim` functions to post process or better use a pattern like "^.+<.*?>|</span>.+$" that will remove both leading and trailing junk.

Comment: If you expect HTML even slightly more complex than this, then you should consider using an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using an html/xml parser, as @Tim Biegeleisen mentiones:

Using `rvest` (which is based on `xml2`) you can do the following:

```
require(rvest)
doc <- read_html( "                                <span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$138,110</span></dd>")
html_text(html_node(doc, "span"))
```

Which gives you `"$138,110"`

Written in a piped (`%>%`) form this becomes

```
doc %>% 
  html_node("span") %>% 
  html_text
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use capture groups (the bit in parentheses):

`\\s` matches whitespace, and `[^<]+` matches one or more characters that aren't `<`.

```
temp <- "                                <span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$138,110</span></dd>"
out <- sub('\\s*<.*>([^<]+)<.*>\\s*', '\\1', temp)
```